# Suppose that $X$ has a uniform distribution on $\left [ 0, \frac{1}{2} \right ]$. Then find pdf of $X^2$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

My solution: Let $Y=X^{2}$. Then $$F_{y}(y)=P(Y \leq y ) = P(X^{2} \leq y) = P(X^{2} \leq \frac{\sqrt{y}}{2}).$$

So $$f_{y}(y) = \frac{1}{4 \sqrt{y}}.$$ Then $$f_{x^{2}}(x) = \frac{1}{4 x}$$

Is my solution correct?

Comment: You made a few typos...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. $X^{2} \leq y$ means $X \leq \sqrt y$, not $X \leq \sqrt y /2$.

$P(X^{2} \leq y)=P(X \leq \sqrt y)=2\sqrt y$ and the density is $\frac 1 {\sqrt y}$ on $(0,\frac  1 4)$.

Comment: Why is it multiplied by 2? Could you please give me an extra step?

Comment: @OGC The density for unifrom distribution on $(0,a)$ is $\frac  1 a$ on that interval. When  $a=\frac  1 2$ we get $\frac  1 a=2$.

Comment: So the correct answer would be $\frac{1}{x}$?

Comment: @OGC The answer is $f_{X^{2}} (y)=\frac  1{\sqrt y}$ for $0 <y <\frac 1  4$. (It doesn't matter whether you write $y$ or $x$ in this final answer).

Comment: But I want to convert it in terms of $x$. So isn't just substituting $x^{2}$ for $y$?

Comment: @OGC $\frac  1 x$ is wrong.

Comment: Okay, thanks. So I guess I can't right the answer in terms of $x$ but instead have to write it in terms of $y$?